# Loops and File Statistics Java Program

Tags: java, loops, file-io

I am have a difficult time writing this program. I am very new to JAVA and I have the basic understanding. But I can't seem to understand what it is asking me to do.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;       
import java.io.*;           

public class StatsDemo
{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException  
    {
        double sum = 0; 
        int count = 0;  
        double mean = 0; 
        double stdDev = 0;
        String line;
        double difference;  //difference between the value and the mean

        DecimalFormat threeDecimals = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        String filename;

        System.out.println("This program calculates statistics"
            + "on a file containing a series of numbers");
        System.out.print("Enter the file name:  ");
        filename = keyboard.nextLine();
```

Here are some of the lines from Number.txt that this program is supposed to be reading from.

```
87.5517
72.14015
88.24248
60.524
65.38684
94.48039
84.73287
84.74978
73.78996
```

Comment: What is your concrete question? You are just stating your homework assignment.

Comment: I am having trouble with Task 4 and 5. I was wondering if someone could tell me why what I wrote is wrong and what I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

- You were asked to use a `FileReader` in the comments. Why do you use a `PrintWriter`? One is for input (reading from a file), the other is for output (writing to a file).
- You did the "priming" and the while loop correctly in task #5. Why didn't you do the same in task #4? You do not have a variable named `inputFile` there.
- In both cases, close the reader, not the file behind it. It will close the file behind it automatically.
- In order to print with the correct number of decimal places, you have to use the `threeDecimals` object you were supplied with. It is of type DecimalFormat. You format the string by using `threeDecimals.format(number)`.

In general, all of the methods available in all of the standard types are in the [Java SE API Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/).

Comment: I made the adjustments. But still getting an error about BufferedReader

Comment: You used `File`, not `FileReader`.

Comment: I have changed task 4 and 5 and I no longer have an error. But now I am getting an error from task 3 which was fine before. It says the line file.print("Mean = " + mean + "; S.D. = " + stdDev); cannot find symbol.

Comment: Do you have a variable called `file`?